# Reguar expression in SQL to match 3 world currency code, but not numbers after currency code

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I'm trying to extract currency codes from a string

String looks like this:
`brand_sportswear|FOOTWEAR_FOOTWEAR_FOOTWEAR|footwear_footwear_footwear|12787274_12016989_12787233|EUR276.94`

With the currency at the end.

If I use 
`'\|[A-Z]{3}[1-9]'` 
I can get the currency at the end, but this is the output:

```
|EUR2
```

How can I pull only the currency code at the end?

It's not really realistic for me to put something like

```
'USD|EUR|JPY'
```

Because I've got a lot of currencies coming through.

Comment: I believe presto allows for lookaheads, but not positive. Try `\|[A-Z]{3}(?=[1-9])` or just substring it.

Comment: thank you @ctwheels, I'm still getting the pipe before the currency code. so |EUR instead of just EUR

Comment: What about just using `substr(string, 2,3)`?

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer, you can use capture groups, might be best method

Comment: marked as answered, thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lookarounds

Presto allows for lookaheads so you can use the following:

```
regexp_extract(string, '\|[A-Z]{3}(?=[1-9])')
```

This won't, however, remove the pipe `|`.

I don't believe Presto allows for lookbehinds at the moment.

---

### Capture Group

Another alternative is to use a capture group:

```
regexp_extract(string, '\|(A-Z{3})[1-9]', 1)
```

---

### Substring

Alternatively, you can just substring your existing regex it using the following:

```
substr(regexp_extract(string, '\|A-Z{3}[1-9]'), 2, 3)
```